# SQLite - Java: Group_concat - Separation

Tags: java, sqlite

I use group_concat to perform a join on a one-to-many relationship.

I'm basically joining file names or user-input strings. Im asking myself what the best divider is. I think that if I use the default `,` this can be problematic when the user input that is stored in the Database has itself a `,`.

Is there a best-practice char I can use for splitting the strings? Something that is really unique so I can retrieve the values safely by using `String.split()`?

Comment: Nothing is fool-proof, but `~` and `|` are commonly used as unlikely-to-appear-in-other-strings separators.

Comment: What characters are allowed in file names depends on the OS.